# ASP.NET MVC + Ninject: InRequestScope

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I want to create instance of PerRequestResourceProvider using ninject InRequestScope:

```
public class PerRequestResourceProvider: IPerRequestResourceProvider
{
    priavte readonly _perRequestResorceInstance;
    public PerRequestResourceProvider()
    {
        _perRequestResorceInstance = new PerRequestResource();
    }
    public PerRequestResource GetResource()
    {
        return _perRequestResorceInstance;
    }
}

public interface IPerRequestResourceProvider
{
     PerRequestResource GetResource();
}
```

In my NinjectDependencyResolver:

```
.....
kernel.Bind<IPerRequestResourceProvider>.To<PerRequestResourceProvider>().InRequestScope();
```

I inject IPerRequestResourceProvider in few classes. But when I add breakpoint to PerRequestResourceProvider constructor I see that PerRequestResourceProvider is created three times during one request and not single per request. What's wrong?

**Update**: source code ttps://bitbucket.org/maximtkachenko/ninjectinrequestscope/src

Comment: if that's the case you should post a minimal - but complete - sample which reproduces the problem. So that we/you can either create a bug report @ ninject or help you solve the problem.
You could create a minimal solution, upload and link it.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I've added source code https://bitbucket.org/maximtkachenko/ninjectinrequestscope/src

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I've fixed HomeController contsructor but result is the same: PerRequestResourceProvider constructor is called 3 times during request.

Comment: yes i observed that too. As far as i've found out yet, i would say that you did not integrated ninject correctly into the solution. It's too bad that ninject is not throwing an exception. I guess you need ninject.MVC3 or ninject.extensions.MVC5 or something like that. The ninject.web.common stuff is IMHO not getting initialized properly.

Comment: see https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc on how to do that

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I've installed Ninject.MVC4 and now it works properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. Ninject is not getting initialized correctly.
   You need one of the Ninject.MVCx packages (according to the MVC version you are using). To configure it correctly, see: http://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc
2. You are injecting `PerRequestResourceProvider` (the class type), and not `IPerRequestResourceProvider` (the interface type) into `HomeController`, thus the `.InRequestScope()` defined on the `IPerRequestResourceProvider` binding is not taking any effect. Change the `HomeController` constructor to get  the inteface type injected and you're good.

---

Ninject does not require bindings for instantiatable (non-abstract,..) classes. This is why it is not obvious when the wrong binding is used.