# Session is closed Object name: 'ISession'. at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.ErrorIfClosed() - How to stop the session from closing prematurely

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, ninject

I am using NHibernate in an MVC C# application with MySQL. I am trying to have multiple users access the session. I have been using `.InRequestScope()` on my session but i am still getting:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Session is closed! Object name: 'ISession'. at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.ErrorIfClosed() *

...or DataReader errors when i have my colleagues all navigate to the same page that accesses a Service at the same time.

**My IMasterSessionSource injection**

```
Bind<IMasterSessionSource>().To<GeneralMasterSessionSource()
                            .InRequestScope();
```

**My IContentService is where my mappings are getting serviced**

```
        //ContentService Bingings
        Bind<IContentService>().To<ContentService>().InRequestScope();
        Bind<ISession>()
            .ToMethod(
                context =>
                    context.Kernel.Get<IMasterSessionSource>()
                        .ExposeConfiguration()
                        .BuildSessionFactory()
                        .OpenSession()
            )
            .WhenInjectedInto<IContentService>()
            .InRequestScope();
```

**ContentService**

```
public interface IContentService
    {
        IQueryable<Question> Questions{ get; }
    }


 public class ContentService : IContentService
    {
        private readonly ISession _session;

        public ContentService(ISession session)
        {
            _session = session;
        }

        public IQueryable<Question> Questions
        {
            get { return _session.Query<Question>(); }
        }
    }
```

**DetailsService**

```
 public interface IDetailsService
    {
        IEnumerable<Question> PullQuestions();
    }

 public class DetailsService : IDetailsService
    {
        private readonly IContentService _contentService;


        public GeneralService(IContentService contentService)
        {
            _contentService = contentService;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Question> PullQuestions()
        {
            var result = _contentService.Questions;
            return result;
        }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public class Test: Controller
    {

        private readonly IContentService _contentService;
        private readonly IGeneralService _generalService;

        public CollegeController(IContentService contentService, IDetailsService detailsService)
        {
            _contentService = contentService;
            _detailsService = detailsService;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            {
                var model = new HomePageContent
                {
                    Questions = _detailsService.PullQuestions().ToList();
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

**MODEL**

```
 public class HomePageContent
    {
        public IEnumerable<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
foreach(var question in Model.Questions){
@Html.Raw(question.Question)
}
```

So for a single user visiting that page. All works fine. But when mutliple users visist the same page each get the errors:

> {"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."}
>   {"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."}
>   {"No current query in data reader"}
>   {"No current query in data reader"}
>   {"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."}
>   {"Session is closed!\r\nObject name: 'ISession'."}

I already added InRequestScope. I even added this implementation:
[NHibernate, and odd "Session is Closed!" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572015/nhibernate-and-odd-session-is-closed-errors)

but I am still getting Sessions are closed! errors. I even tried to create a new Kernel.Get if the session was closed, but the problem is that the error sometimes occurs even when the session is open. Please help! I am at wits end with this issue, and I can't seem to find the solution anywhere. I almost think it's impossible for NHibernate to handle more than one session at once.

**UPDATE**

Maybe there's a way to wait for disposed session before opening new?

**Stack Trace**

> [ObjectDisposedException: Session is closed! Object name: 'ISession'.]
>   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.ErrorIfClosed() +192
>   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CheckAndUpdateSessionStatus() +55 
>   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression) +171
>   NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression
>   expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery) +226
>   NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
>   +80    NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +74    Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator() +193 
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +432
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +70
>   Gcus.PublicGeneralSite.Data.Core.Service.General.DetailsService.FindItems(String
>   item, String controller) in
>   c:\Users\wd\Desktop\master\Gcus.PublicGeneralSite.Data.Core\Service\General\DetailsService.cs:724
>   Gcus.Com.Web.Controllers.CoursesController.Details(String category,
>   String item) in
>   c:\Users\wd\Desktop\master\Gcus.Com.Web\Controllers\CoursesController.cs:213
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +366
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +87
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +603
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +93
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
>   +97    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +53
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +137
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +187
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +136
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +76
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +164    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +549    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +75
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +79
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +187
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +136
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +76
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +114    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +306
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +75
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +176
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +72
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +70
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +135
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +176
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +72
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +51
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +98
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +176
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +72
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +51    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +70
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +135
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +176
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +72
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +51
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +60    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +59
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +399    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137

Comment: NHibernate certainly have no problem with multiple concurrent sessions. In fact, it's designed to handle precisely that scenario. It cannot however handle concurrent access to a _single_ session. The session is not threadsafe. You do seem to be aware of this, since you speak about InRequestScope() etc, which sounds like it should do the trick. It seems this is more of a problem with ninject (or how you use it) than NHibernate.

Comment: Maybe you haven't set up NInject properly for MVC?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928070/asp-net-mvc-ninject-inrequestscope

Comment: i have it set up properly. I'm using NInject.MVC5 and injecting them into the correct controllers. The problem seem to be when there's two requests for the same session. Somehow one maybe has to wait till connection closed. But i'm not sure. I just cant believe this is so difficult.

Comment: Let me repeat this: NHibernate is designed to handle multiple concurrent threads, sessions and connections. Bugs do happen, but this is very unlikely to be a problem in NHibernate. However, the NHibernate rule (simply put) that must be followed is that a single session instance AND any data loaded from the session must be used from ONLY 1 thread at a time.

Comment: So this is not about "waiting for a session to be disposed" or something like that. Multiple sessions are fine. The solution to the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Can we see some stacktraces from the exceptions you're getting? Are you sure that you are not accidentally sharing some loaded data between different requests?

Comment: @Oskar Berggen - I added a stack trace in the update. I really appreciate your feedback. I am not sure if its sharing loaded data. I think maybe MySQL is closing the session. But i have no idea.

Comment: Well, the stack trace mentions DetailsService - is that setup the same way as in the code you show? There is also a lot about "async" in the stack trace but I'm afraid it's difficult to understand how all that relates to NInject's InRequestScope(). Are you in anyway moving sessions around yourself? Or opening/closing/disposing them outside ninject?

Comment: @OskarBerggren - In my example i put GeneralService, but DetailService is roughly the same type of service. A service that handles session queries. I updated the question to reflect DetailService. I don't know why its doing an async wrapper. But i don't think that's related to the main problem with Sessions.

Comment: Unless the problem is in the ninject setup (which I'm not familiar with) there is simply not enough information here to be able to understand the issue.

Comment: well it just seems like ISession might be Shared. I think i need to figure out how to have multiple sessions per request. :( i definately need help with how to do that. Cant find answers anywhere on examples.

Comment: Are you using System.Transactions/ambient transations, or ONLY session.BeginTransaction()?

Comment: for the normal queries i am using the ContentService seen above. but for writing and updating i am using BeginTransaction() but my error is only when a session is using a connect and another session cannot access that connection. or when the connection closes on another session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Much appreciation to @Oskar Berggren for at least being avid on understanding my dilemma.

The problem was that I, in fact, was sharing one session all along.

*here is where i am binding an open session to ContentService:*

```
 Bind<IContentService>().To<ContentService>().InRequestScope();
        Bind<ISession>()
            .ToMethod(
                context =>
                    context.Kernel.Get<IMasterSessionSource>()
                        .ExposeConfiguration()
                        .BuildSessionFactory()
                        .OpenSession()
            )
            .WhenInjectedInto<IContentService>()
            .InRequestScope();
```

*Here is where i am calling the same session in ContentService*

```
 public class ContentService : IContentService
    {
        private readonly ISession _session;

        public ContentService(ISession session)
        {
            _session = session;
        }

        public IQueryable<Question> Questions
        {
            get { return _session.Query<Question>(); }
        }
    }
```

*Here is where the problem is. I am calling the SAME session in another service that is being used elsewhere*

```
public class DetailsService : IDetailsService
    {
        private readonly IContentService _contentService; //BAD


        public GeneralService(IContentService contentService)
        {
            _contentService = contentService; //BAD
        }
```

This is not thread safe, because that one open session is getting reused. **Each service should have its own session.**

so i created binding for DetailService with its own session like so....

```
 Bind<IDetailsService>()
                .To<DetailsService>()
                .InRequestScope();

            Bind<ISession>()
                .ToMethod(
                    context =>
                    {
                        var lockObject = new object();

                        lock (lockObject)
                        {
                            return context.Kernel.Get<IMasterSessionSource>()
                                .ExposeConfiguration()
                                .BuildSessionFactory()
                                .OpenSession();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .WhenInjectedInto<IDetailsService>()
                .InRequestScope();
```

And instead of calling _contentService in that service i added the session to its constrictor

```
    private readonly ISession Session;

    public DetailsService(ISession session)
    {
        Session = session;
    }
```

then just ran queries directly using Session.Query();

no more Session is closed errors, no more DataReader Errors, and finally a working product.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with ninject, which I suspect is involved in the problem here.

If you cannot figure out how to make that handle the sessions properly, you may have a look at NHibernate's own handling of contextual sessions: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/architecture.html#architecture-current-session

Comment: So it turns out that its not the sessions that's the problem... MySQL seems to close the session prematurely on other threads. But i still have no idea why and cannot find a fix for this anywhere.